# Having trouble downloading dynamic web content with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, download, web, phantomjs

My goal is to download the dynamic web content of a website, so javascript is necessary to be executed on the received content. The code that I am currently using with PhantomJS 2.1 is the following:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.open('https://sports.bovada.lv/soccer/premier-league', function () {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function () {
        page.evaluate(); // Edit: this line is removed
        page.close();
    });
});

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    console.log("Download finished");
    fs.write('test.html', page.content, 'w');
    phantom.exit(0);
};
```

The code is saving the received page as "test.html", but unfortunately it is not loading the full page content as it does with a web browser. I would appreciate if someone could help me out.

Website used for testing: https://sports.bovada.lv/soccer/premier-league

Comment: This site can’t be reached  
sports.bovada.lv unexpectedly closed the connection.  
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: It can happen that the site has geolocation restrictions. Anyway you experiment with another site for example http://www.foxsports.com/soccer/scores?competition=1

Comment: Why do you use both `page.onLoadFinished` and the callback of `page.open`. You only need one of them, because they are equivalent if you open only one page. Also, what's `page.evaluate();` supposed to accomplish? Furthermore, loading an old version of jQuery might break the page. Try to rely on the jQuery version that comes with the page.

Comment: I am using PhantomJS the first time and this what I could achieve based on the provided documentation. Can I provide also the URL if I use only page.onLoadFinished? Furthermore how should set it to use the jQuery version that comes with the page? By the way I tried to omit page.open and use only page.onLoadFinished, but it never downloaded the page.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be that your're exiting too soon. Try delaying script termination:

```
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    console.log("Download finished");
    fs.write('test.html', page.content, 'w');
    setTimeout(function(){
        phantom.exit(0);
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. The page is still not downloaded properly. It is still shown just like as I statically downloaded it with CURL.